# flutter fatal error: module 'FBSDKCoreKit' not found

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using `flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0`

I got this error when i tried to run my app

> ** BUILD FAILED ** Xcode's output: ↳ In file included from /Users/*****/*****/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/_FBSDKLoginRecoveryAttempter.m:21:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/*****/*****/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginKit+Internal.h:19:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/*****/*****/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/../FBSDKLoginKit.h:27:
>   /Users/*****/*****/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:24:9:
>   fatal error: module 'FBSDKCoreKit' not found @import FBSDKCoreKit;
>
> ```
> for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 8.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to solve this issue by changing the Podfile

```
target 'Runner' do
# flutter Pod
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
------
```

flutter clean

Delete Podfile.lock

pod install --repo-update

pod update FBSDKLoginKit

Run

```
flutter clean && cd ios && sudo rm Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update && pod update FBSDKLoginKit
```

open .xcworkspace and in General-> Deployment Info set Target 11.0 also in Podfile set Target 11.0

Answer (score 2):

Until now the only way that worked for me was [this](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/214)

You will have to override Podfile.lock with 5.8.0 version of Facebook SDK.

```
PODS:
  - FBSDKCoreKit (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 5.8.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 5.8.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (5.8.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
  - FBSDKLoginKit (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 5.8.0)
  - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (5.8.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.0)
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
....
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been around the houses and back with this and have eventually got this to work with the `5.13.1` Podfiles on iOS (by work, I mean compiling, linking and installing onto a real iPhone - I don't actually use Facebook but it's required as part of the firebase-ui login package  :-D )

Firstly, do a pod clean, e.g.

```
Run: flutter clean
Go to ios folder, delete Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder, Runner.xcworkspace
Run project again
```

After building I got errors regarding:

```
fatal error: module 'FBSDKCoreKit' not found
    @import FBSDKCoreKit;
```

I then added the modular headers override into the ios/podspec file mentioned here https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/214#issuecomment-565166295

The start of the podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

use_modular_headers!
```

I did note that linking errors, about missing Facebook libraries, were due to a spurious entry in the Frameworks section.

Futher details in [this thread](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/222#issuecomment-570784262)

Answer (score 2):

I had resolved it by following below steps, I had faced this issue due to facebook_share plugin so

1.downgrade the version of facebook_share plugin to. 0.0.1+1 
2.run command in your project's terminal - pod cache clean —all 
3.add below two pods in Podfile:

```
target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 6.0.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 6.0.0'
```

4.run command in your project's terminal - Pod install 
5.run command in your project's terminal - pod update FBSDKShareKit

done, error removed

Answer (score 1):

This issue solved my problem ['FBSDKCoreKit / FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/452)

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.38'
```